# Best he-aac encoder on linux?

Tags: encoding, mp3, aac, aac+

I need an encoder that can convert mp3 files to he-aac (aka aac+).
So far the best one I have found is [nero aac encoder](http://www.nero.com/eng/down-ndaudio.php) . 
I have two problemes with it :
  - Only one input format : wav . It is a little bit slow to transform mp3 files to wav and then to he-aac.
  - a free license for **non commercial** use.

Too bad ffmpeg does not support he-aac ...
There is a commercial solution, [on2 flix](https://flix.on2.com/), but it seems to be a golden hammer for the simple task I need to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nero AAC is the only one as far as I know.  Even if FAAC supported HE-AAC it would be useless, since as an encoder its pretty awfully designed and its quality is not even competitive with LAME, let alone a good AAC encoder.

Kostya on the FFMPEG team is currently working on an AAC encoder but it has a long way to go--its not ready for primetime with LC-AAC, let alone HE-AAC (its not even committed to the repository yet).  The first step before anything will be to get the ffmpeg decoder to support HE-AAC; currently it can only be decoded through FAAD.

I don't believe there is *any* HE-AAC encoder on any platform with a more permissive license than Nero's at this point in time.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using `neroAacEnc` for quite a while now, and I'm largely satisfied with the results. If you're on Linux, making an `.AAC` file out of an `.MP3` or whatever else, is quite easy, all you need is a small wrapper script, that takes care of decoding into `.WAV` and after encoding, removes the `.WAV` file.

Be advised: Converting from one lossy encoding to another further reduces quality. So when you can live with `.MP3` and you don't have lossless sources, you better stick to them.

Here's a small script, that converts from `.FLAC`to `.AAC`, it accepts only `.FLAC` files as arguments:

```
#!/bin/zsh

for file in ${argv[*]}; do
    flac -d ${file}
    neroAacEnc -q 0.6 -if ${file%%.flac}.wav -of ${file%%.flac}.aac
    rm ${file%%.flac}.wav
done
```

This script is sequential, but it can be easily made into a multithreaded script.

Answer (score 2):

There is an encoder called `accplus` which is under the GNU license [available here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libaacplus_8c-source.html).

Comment: The link goes to ffmpeg's libaacplus interface, which only does AAC-LC (not a limitation of libaacplus). The real libaacplus can be found at [this github mirror](https://github.com/Distrotech/libaacplus).

Answer (score 1):

Another encoder: [mp4tools](http://teknoraver.net/software/mp4tools/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea about the quality, but I just found
[enhAacPlusEnc](http://dgaapenc.berlios.de/en/)